# Apply different data to a function in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(1, 100, 1),
  y = rnorm(100)
)
```

Where I apply a smooth spline using different knots:

```
nknots <- seq(4, 15, 1)

output <- map(nknots, ~ smooth.spline(x = df$x, y = df$y, nknots = .x))
```

What I need to do now is to apply the same function using 2-point and 3-point averages:

```
df_2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(., x = round(.$x/2)*2) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean))

df_3 <- df %>% 
  group_by(., x = round(.$x/3)*3) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean))
```

In summary, I need to apply the function I used in `output` with the following data frames:

- df
- df_2
- df_3

Of course, this is a minimal example, so I am looking for a efficient way of doing it. Preferably with the `purrr` package.

Comment: You can create a list and use `lapply` or one of it's alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 100, 1),
                 y = rnorm(100))

# funtion to get v-point averages
GetAverages = function(v) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(., x = round(.$x/v)*v) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(mean)) }

# specify nunber of knots
nknots <- seq(4, 15, 1)


dt_res = tibble(v=1:3) %>%                     # specify v-point averages
  mutate(d = map(v, GetAverages)) %>%          # get data for each v-point 
  crossing(., data.frame(nknots=nknots)) %>%   # combine each dataset with a knot
  mutate(res = map2(d, nknots, ~smooth.spline(x = .x$x, y = .x$y, nknots = .y)))  # apply smooth spline
```

You can use `dt_res$res[dt_res$v == 1]` to see all results for your original daatset, `dt_res$res[dt_res$v == 2]` to see results for your 2-point estimate, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using lapply, and the library `zoo` to calculate the moving average in a more simple and elegant manner:

```
library(zoo)

lapply(1:3,function(roll){
  dftemp <- as.data.frame(rollmean(df,roll))
  map(nknots, ~ smooth.spline(x = dftemp$x, y = dftemp$y, nknots = .x))
  })
```